# Does map.namespace falls back in case if there is no matching controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Today I am observing a peculiar behavior in my rails app.

I have defined the following route in routes.rb

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
 admin.resources :users
end
```

and when I use rake:routes, I see the following routes as expected:

```
admin_users GET /admin/users {:action => 'index, :controller => 'admin/users'}
....
....
```

which are perfectly namespaced both in terms of path_prefixes as well as name_prefixes.

I have the UsersController under app/controllers (not under app/controllers/admin), but somehow rails is picking up the UsersController under app/controllers instead of app/controllers/admin, is this a recent change in rails, where it falls back for the controller, when it doesn't find one?

Comment: Can you show an example of the actual url generated in the page?

Answer (score 0):

It might be getting picked up by the default routes included at the bottom of routes.rb.

```
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

For your purposes, it sounds like removing these may be a good idea.

Comment: @Dave: Thanks for the feedback. Actually I removed those default routes a while ago. Even then with the default routes in place, admin/users/:id is also being picked using UsersController instead of Admin::UsersController. I don't understand why rails is picking the wrong controller.